# Sending value of select list with uploadify

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making an upload script with uploadif jquery plugin. I want to send HTML select list value with uploadify to mysql. Code like not doesen't work. It writes everything to MySQL DB except that HTML select list value.

```
 var kategorija = $("#kategorija").val();

 $('#file_upload').uploadify({
    'uploader'  : '/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
    'script'    : '/uploadify/uploadify.php',
    'cancelImg' : '/uploadify/cancel.png',
    'multi'     : true,
    'auto'      : false,
    'folder'    : '/uploads',
    'sizeLimit' : '5242880',
    'queueSizeLimit' : 10,

    'onQueueFull' : function(event, queueSizeLimit)
    {
        alert("Najvecje stevilo datotek, ki jih lahko naenkrat nalozite je " + queueSizeLimit);
        return false;
    },
    'onComplete' : function(event, ID, fileObj, response, data)
    {
        $.post("insert.php", {name: fileObj.name, lol: krnekiup, path: fileObj.filePath, kategorija: kategorija}, function(info)
        {
        });
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try retrieving the value inside your `onComplete` callback instead:

```
'onComplete': function(event, ID, fileObj, response, data)
{
    var kategorija = $("#kategorija").val();

    $.post( ...
```

If that doesn't work, put a breakpoint on the `$.post` in Firebug (or whatever your preferred debugger is) and check the value of `kategorija`.

Answer (score 0):

just add this code:

```
'onUploadStart': function(event, data) { 
            selected_index = document.getElementById("des").selectedIndex;
            var albumID = document.getElementById("des").options[selected_index].value;
            jQuery("#upload_btn").uploadify('settings','formData', {'des' : albumID});
          }
```

description :
   `"des"` is the id of you select tag.
   and des near the `formData` code is like a name. `($_POST['des'])`

we had the same problem and i hardwork to solve this. LOL

note: i got reference from [here](http://webcodingeasy.com/Implementing-scripts/Uploadify-with-album-select)